# Reverse for url with arguments not found in Django

Tags: python, django, url, view

*Error: Reverse for 'task_list_by_tag' with arguments '('оаип_1',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['tag/(?P<tag_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\Z']*

**views.py**

```
def index(request, tag_slug=None):
    task_list = Task.objects.all()
    
    tag = None

    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
        task_list = task_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])

    paginator = Paginator(task_list, 2)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    try:
        tasks = paginator.page(page_number)

    context = {"tasks":tasks, 'tag':tag}

    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'main'
...
path('tag/<slug:tag_slug>/', views.index, name = "task_list_by_tag"),
```

**index.html**

```
{% for tag in task.tags.all %}
       <a href="{% url "main:task_list_by_tag" tag.slug %}">
           {{ tag.name }}
       </a>
{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I tried to fix that problem:

1)

```
<a href="{% url "main:task_list_by_tag" tag_slug=tag.slug %}">
```

return the error:
*Reverse for 'task_list_by_tag' with keyword arguments '{'tag_slug': 'оаип_1'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['tag/(?P<tag_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\Z']*

2)

```
`<a href="{% url "main:task_list_by_tag" slug=tag.slug %}">`
```

*Reverse for 'task_list_by_tag' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'оаип_1'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['tag/(?P<tag_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\Z']*

Comment: slugs don't have underscores...

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike as per [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) it should handle underscores. Problem could be non-ASCII characters.

Comment: It might just be a problem with single versus double quotes.  Try changing your `<a href="{% url "main:task_list_by_tag" tag.slug %}">` to this: `<a href="{% url 'main:task_list_by_tag' tag.slug %}">`

Comment: @Marco: aargghh, I didn't see that it was cyrillic. No that will indeed not work, the slug only accepts ASCII alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `<a href="{% url "main:task_list_by_tag" tag.slug %}">` is perfectly fine as Django has found the correct URL mentioned in:

```
Error: Reverse for 'task_list_by_tag' with arguments '('оаип_1',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['tag/(?P<tag_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\Z']
```

But as per [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters), you can only use "ASCII letters or numbers, plus the hyphen and underscore characters" for slugs:

> slug - Matches any slug string consisting of ASCII letters or numbers, plus the hyphen and underscore characters. For example, building-your-1st-django-site.

Make sure that your slug consists only of these characters and not Cyrillic, as you are doing now. Otherwise, change your URL dispatcher to `str`.

Comment: your answer is correct. it helped me. thank u